# Nginx gzip more then 70%

Tags: nginx, gzip

i testing in pingdom website and i get Compression reduces response times by reducing the size of the HTTP response. Gzip is the most popular and effective compression method currently available and generally reduces the response size by about 70%. Approximately 90% of today's Internet traffic travels through browsers that claim to support gzip.

i have only 59% how to do 70% and more? i try different settings not helping.

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\\.(?!.*SV1)";
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 5;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-icon image/bmp image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;
```

Comment: You adjust the setting gzip_comp_level to up to 9. Compression level 6 is a good value between compression cost (server cpu) and compresssion size

Comment: Already try same still 59% and in other test pages 80-81% but still same don't change results.